# Join and process results in Java vs multiple queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I am working with SQL and Spring and I had this doubt for a long time. Let's say I have this tables in my SQL db: user, items_a, items_b, user_items_a, user_items_b.

user table:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | Paul |
| 3 | Dan |

user_items_a table

| USER ID | ITEM_A_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 1 | 22 |

user_items_b table

| USER ID | ITEM_B_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 232 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 15 |

items_b and items_b contain relevant data to that entity that we will need to retrieve but it is not important to detail here.

Now, User class is:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<ItemA> itemsA;
    private List<ItemB> itemsB;
}
```

I am using JDBC.

My question is, when we get a list of users, which options is better performance wise?

Option A, Join all tables and process them in a HashMap:

```
private List<User> getUsers() {
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM user
                   LEFT JOIN user_items_a uia ON uia.user_id = user.id
                   LEFT JOIN items_a ia ON ia.id = uia.id
                   LEFT JOIN user_items_b uib ON uib.user_id = user.id
                   LEFT JOIN items_b ib ON ib.id = uib.id"

        class AuxRow {
            Long id;
            String name;
            Long item_a_id;
            Long item_b_id;
            String item_a_value;
            String item_b_value;
            

            public AuxRow() {
            }

        }

        RowMapper<AuxRow> rm = (rs, rowNum)->{
            AuxRow aux = new AuxRow();
            aux.id= rs.getInt("id");
            //Set all values.....
            return aux;
        };

        List<Aux> result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rm);
     
        // Map of <user_id, User>
        Map<Long, Users> usersMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Aux aux : result){
            if(userMap.containsKey(aux.id)) {
                //add item_a/item_b to list checking if it is not duplicated, maybe we can use a Set here
            } else {
                // Create user and add it to the map
            }
        }

        return usersMap.values();
}
```

Option B, query user items individually:

```
private List<User> getUsers() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user"

        List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rm);
     
        for(User user : users){
            //Query items A
            user.setItemsA(jdbcTemplate.query(......));
            //Query items B
            user.setItemsB(jdbcTemplate.query(......));
        }

        return users;
}
```

Option C, same as B but query all items A in the same query and then add to each user accordingly, then do the same for items B.

```
private List<User> getUsers() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user"

        List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rm);
        //query all items a for every user fetched before
        List<ItemsA> itemsA = jdbcTemplate.query(......));
        //query all items b for every user fetched before
        List<ItemsB> itemsB = jdbcTemplate.query(......));
        Map<Long, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        // Populate map with <userId, User>
        for(ItemA item: itemsA){
            User user = userMap.get(item.userId);
            user.getItemsA.add(item);
        }
        for(ItemB item: itemsB){
            User user = userMap.get(item.userId);
            user.getItemsB.add(item);
        }
        return users;
}
```

IMO I would guess Option B would be better in cases where users are queried with a LIMIT because of code simplicity and we wouldn't be doing a lot of queries. But if we were to query a lot of users, I would go with option B. Option C seems like in the middle of A and B. Again, this is my guess, I wanted to hear people who knows better than me :)

Thank you!

Comment: I assume this is an academic exercise, because you can do it with annotations without do queries manually. The option A, it's great when you have a few ItemA and ItemB by user, because only with 1 access you get all information. The option B, it's one basic implementation that calls a lot of times the DB. The option C, calls the DB 3 times, and seams to be the best implementation. My opinion is, the option C better than A, and A better than B

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm guessing you haven't tried benchmarking since there doesn't seem to be a mention of it in your post. Is there a particular reason you haven't?